# Scan Activity into Fragment View

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, zxing

I'm trying to incoorporate a scanner in my android app. It works, however it fills out the whole screen. I'm using a Fragment component to contain the scanner. I would like it to be shown only on the top half of the screen, as I have illustrated it in the figure below. I have provided the code example to show, how the scanner is activated. Can anyone help me with this issue? In the code below I have inflated a view, after which I never make use of it. Is this the main issue?

```
private static final int sSCAN_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
private static final String SCAN_ACTION = PACKAGE_NAME + ".SCAN";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(SCAN_ACTION);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, sSCAN_REQUEST_CODE);

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan, container, false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the intent, if you want it to be on just half your screen you would have to create a custom scanner. There are a couple of different libraries, search for them.